# Run terminal command from VIM?

Tags: vim

I wish to write a function which I can add to my .vimrc file that will call a terminal command, and then bind it to `<leader>u`.

I cant seem to get it to work tho.  I believe that I can use the system() function, but there is very little documentation available and I cant seem to get it to work.

The terminal command in question is '*git push origin master*'.

I know that there are plugins available for git but I am not looking for any of these, just a simple function to bind a terminal command to a key combination.

```
function gitPush()
 system("git push origin master")
endfunction
:nmap <leader>u :call gitPush()
```

I know this is waaay out, but vim doesnt seem to want to make documentation very available.

Ty

Comment: You do know about `:help`, right? `:help system()` shows documentation for the `system()` function. `:help shell` gives you documentation for the `shell` command, and right beneath it you'll see the documentation for the `!` command (what you probably want).

Comment: On a related note, if your purpose for wanting shell commands is to interact with git, you'd be much better off using one of the git-related Vim plugins, like 'fugitive' or VCSCommand.  Here's link to fugitive page: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function GitPush()
    !git push origin master
endfunction
```

Is the way to run a command in a subshell.

EDIT: User defined functions must begin with a capital letter too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `call` to call your own function and fail to use it for builtin? It is one of three errors, other was mentioned by @Richo: user-defined function must either start with a capital or with `b:`, `w:`, `t:` (note that neither of these are local functions), `g:`, `s:` (only inside scripts, and you will have to replace `s:` with `<SID>` in mappings), even `\w:` (for example, `function _:foo()` works) or with `{filename_without_extension}#` (if filename matches `\w+.vim`). If it is anonymous function:

```
let dict={}
function dict["foo"]()
endfunction
function dict.bar()
endfunction
```

it also does not require to start with a capital. So the correct solution is:

```
function g:gitPush()
  call system("git push origin master")
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>u :call g:gitPush()<CR>
```

Third error is omitting `<CR>`. I changed `nmap` to `nnoremap` because it is good to use `nore` where possible. Having `:` at the start of the command does not hurt and is not an error, but I just do not write it: it is required in normal mode mappings to start command mode, but not inside scripts.